# Reg ex for /something/<Any alpha numeric and ->/

Tags: java, regex

I want a regex which compares Alphanumeric and "-". and returns 123ABC-4CDE56 from below string. I have tried below code but it is not working.

```
            String regex = "^/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

        String str = "/something/123ABC-4CDE56/somethingmoretobeignored";

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

        if(matcher.reset(str).find()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`^` and `$` mean start and end of line respectively. So:

```
String regex = "/[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+/";
```

Also, you're saying `.group(1)`, this returns the first thing in brackets `()`, which there are none of. So you'd want to change your regex to:

```
String regex = "/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/";
```

To match start and end of string correctly:

```
String regex = "(^|/)([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(/|$)";
```

Remember now you'll have to use `.group(2)`.

Also `something` and `somethingmoretobeignored` are both alpha-numeric, maybe ignore lower-case:

```
String regex = "(^|/)([A-Z0-9_]+)(/|$)";
```